# problem when Trigger Lambda with s3 event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a problem when i want to trigger my lambda with a s3 event.

I have a first lamda that write in s3 which is supposed to trigger the second lambda. But when it triggers, it is written `Forbidden: PermissionError` when it read the file at a given path.

It is stange because when i upload a file directly to the s3 manually, the trigger works and the lambda works as well.

Does someone already get this error ?

Comment: Please check this to grant permission to your lambda for your s3 bucket. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/

Comment: Check your lambda Execution role(IAM role) has correct permission to execute s3 operations. For more info check here 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html#add-policies-console

Comment: Thank you both of you !